# two conditions in if statement codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

hi i am doing this login where i do if and else statement to check if the user can access that. i have this part where two or more types of user can access this part but not all users.. i have done

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['datauser'] as $a){ 

if($a->USERTYPE == '1' || $a->USERTYPE == '2'){

?>   do this

<?php }} ?>
```

but if it happens that for each of the condition that is true, it does the condition for example

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['datauser'] as $a){ 

if($a->USERTYPE == '1' || $a->USERTYPE == '2'){

   echo 'name';

 }} ?>
```

if usertype == 1 and ==2 it outputs `namename`

i want is if usertype == 1 it will output name if usertype is == it will output also name, if usertype is both, it will also output name.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is expected result?

Comment: please remove extra php from the second block of code.

Comment: the output seems correct, how with the `usertype` be both? please clarify that part

Comment: the output will be parts of my sidebar.

Comment: Are there multiple `user` in session at same time?

Comment: Just a note you can use codeigniter session userdata if you have loaded the library instead of `$_SESSION['datauser']` you can get codeigniter session data `$this->session->userdata('datauser');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use break to end the loop once the condition is true once, e.g.

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['datauser'] as $a){ 

    if($a->USERTYPE == '1' || $a->USERTYPE == '2'){

       echo 'name';
       break;
    }
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
$a="";
foreach($_SESSION['datauser'] as $a){ 
if($a->USERTYPE == '1' || $a->USERTYPE == '2'){
  $a='name';
 }
} 
echo $a;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the since variable `$_SESSION['datauser']` is having multiple value.

your foreach is looping multiple time hence answer is coming `namename`.

incase you want only one name to be print.

try the below code.

```
<?php $name="";
    foreach($_SESSION['datauser'] as $a){ 

    if($a->USERTYPE == '1' || $a->USERTYPE == '2'){
       if($name==""){
          $name="name"; 
       }
    }
}
$name
?>
```